# dynamic dropdown menu ancestry and rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, menu, ancestry

Hi I have try to do dynamic drop down menu using ancestry and rails 3.2 but don't have to much experience with javascript. 
I have got categories with ancestry tree and Ads (model/controller). Ads should have one category. So my idea is when I create a Ad I will chose from dropdown menu category.
In categories for example I've got

-Cars
 - Alfa Romeo
 - -145
 - -146
 - Audi
 - -A4
How should I change or create javascript to get first category.roots, after chose Cars get (alfa romeo, audi) after chose audi get models?
[I've try to folow this link railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) but dont know how to change javascript.

javascript_controller

```
class JavascriptsController < ApplicationController
```

def dynamic_category
    @categories = Category.roots.all

end
end

dynamic_category.js.erb

```
var categories = new Array();
<% for category in @categories %>
    category.push(new Array('<%= category.title %>', <%= category.id %>));
<% end -%>

function categorySelected() {
    category_id = $('ad_category_id').getValue();
    children = $('ad_category_id').children;
    children.lenght = 1;
    categories.each(function(category) {
    if (category.children[0] == category.id) {
    children[children.lenght] = new Child(category[1], category[2]);
}});
if (children.lenght == 1) {
    $('category_field').hide();
    }else {
    $('category_field').show();
    }
}
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('category_field').hide();
    $('ad_category_id').observe('change', categorySelected);
});
```

And what should I put in the ad _form.html.erb after this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:category_id, "Select Category") %><br >
  <%= f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|s| [s.title, s.id]}, :prompt => "Select something") %>
</div>
<% javascript 'dynamic_category' %>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please rewrite the description so that we can see exactly what you're trying achieve. 
Also: there are multiple typos in your javascript, for example on line 3 and in the last if-statement. Please fix these.

Comment: Further questions: what exactly is to happen when the user selects a root category? How deep is the category tree?

Comment: Also: please observe that the Railscast that you are following is 4 years old, jQuery has changed since then.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I wanna do something like dynamic category selection. I'm using ancestry for categories, I've got in root "Cars" then children_stage1 = CarMarke(Honda), children_stage2 = CarModel(civic). 
When I create advert I want to have chance to select first Cars-> then CarMarke then CarModel. And the problem is I dont know how to change this script